# Access to internal object fields in Js

Tags: javascript, oop, reflection

Having this code

```
var a = {date : 12};
for(var t in a){
    alert(t);
}
```

I have one alert with date property.

But everywhere (i.e. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)) i see that it is needed to write :

```
for (var property in object) {
    if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

So why i don't see internal properties of object?

Comment: What do you mean by 'internal properties'. In your last example you just make an edge test if the property you're looking for actually exists in 'your object'.

Comment: which internal properties do you want to see?

Comment: Op says _"why it's required to use `hasOwnProperty`, because i don't see internal props even i didn't use `hasOwnProperty`, so why do i need it?"_ IMHO

Comment: if in console i'll create var a = {a : 1}; and on the next line will type a. i'll see a lot of properties: constructor, isPrototypeOf ... and i guess hasOwnProperty used exactly for the case when i don't want to iterate through them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The for..in syntax iterates every property of the object, including those found on the prototype chain *(if they are enumerable)*. This is usually not what you want, so the `hasOwnProperty` check is usually recommended.

In your case it's not necessary, as your plain object doesn't inherit any enumerable properties from the Object prototype (the only thing in its prototype chain)

Also, for..in gives you the property *names* (keys) of the object, if you're interested in the value of that particular property, you have to use the bracket notation, extending your example to this:

```
var a = {date : 12};
for(var t in a){
    alert(a[t]);
}
```

Comment: what about system fields for every js object? isPrototypeOf, constructor, __defineGetter__? Don't i have to see 'em?

Comment: What do you mean by "have to see them"? They are non-enumerable, so they won't show up when you do a for..in iteration, with or without the hasOwnProperty check. But you *can* reference them directly, if you need to.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript there exists the 'prototype chain', a form of inheritance. If you were to add a property to the prototype of `a`, and then add your `date` property directly onto `a`, your `for` loop would find both those properties.

The `hasOwnProperty` checks whether the current property has been attached directly to the context object or whether it has been inherited through the prototype chain.

So in my example, if you *had* added a property to `a`'s prototype, the `hasOwnProperty` condition would return false and you wouldn't "do stuff" with it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to see it is through an example:

```
Object.prototype.aBaseProperty = 123;

var childObject = { date: 12 };

for (var property in childObject) {
    console.log(property)
}

// output: date aBaseProperty


for (var property in childObject) {
    if (childObject.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
        console.log(property)
    }
}

// output:  date
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, rather than doing the `hasOwnProperty` check, you might prefer

```
Object.keys(object).forEach(function(value, key) { ... });
```

Where `Object.keys` will only return own properties.